# Why is my function working when called by itself but not when I call it with another function? (Beginner javascript question)

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on some coding challenges (I am still a beginner). I was able to make both of these functions work, but when I try to call them together my second function just returns zero..

Both functions take in two parameters (or more). The first function counts the numbers between the two paramters and returns them in a string (1, 5) => [1,2,3,4,5] and the second sums them together (1,10) => 55. Any reason why these work individually but not together?

Thanks in advance!

```
`let range = (start, end) => {
    numbers = [];
    for(i = start; i<end+1; i++) {
      if(i>=start){
      numbers.push(i);
        if (i>=end) {
          console.log(numbers);
        }
      }
    }

}

function sum(start, ...add){ 
    let sumCounter = 0; 
      for(i = start; i<=add; i++) {
        sumCounter += i;
    }
    return sumCounter;
} 

console.log(sum(1,10)); //second function works

console.log(sum(range(1, 10))); //first function works, not second function `
```

Comment: `returns them in a string` - no, it outputs to the console, and returns `undefined` - console.log does not work like return - if you want to return a value from a function, use return

Comment: also .. `...add` would make the variable `add` in the sum function an ARRAY

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things going on here. First make sure that you’re returning a value in the first function, and not just printing to the console. Second, when you say “if(i>=end)” that will always be true, so it isn’t needed. Also instead of saying “if(I>=end)” you can put “I==end” or just put the following code after the for loop. I would suggest that you return the numbers, and take that as a parameter for your sum function. I hope you’re able to follow all of that!

Comment: I followed :) Thank you so much for the response. Much clearer now thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working option:

```
function range(start, end) {
    var numbers = [];
    for (i=start;i<end+1;i++) {
        numbers.push(i)
    } 
    return numbers;
}

console.log("Sum: " + range(5, 10).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0));
```

Or this might be easier to understand:

```
function range(start, end) {
    var numbers = [];
    for (i=start;i<end+1;i++) {
      numbers.push(i)
    } 
    return numbers;
}

function sum(nums) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log("Sum: " + sum(range(5, 10)));
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys! Just relooked at my code and how many mistakes i had. Thanks so much for pointing them all out! I think I have a much better understanding of this now. Not sure why I was receiving downvotes for this question though.. Oh well, thank you for answering!